# BIRT (maximo data): overloaded fetch script in scripted dataSet

Tags: javascript, birt, maximo

I've inherited a BIRT .rptdesign that isn't returning any records in "preview results." There is one open script involved, as well as a fetch script that has approximately 5 more sql queries inside of it. Much of what I have tried for solutions involves breaking out these queries involved in the fetch script into their own dataSet, and then relating them to the open script (alternatively I've tried forming a joint data set, with no luck). Even after taking out a small query from the fetch script, I'm not able to generate records in result preview. I tried to upload an image of the layout, but don't have the reputation to do so...Please let me know if you need the design file to help visualize where everything is landing!

Open script:

```
maximoDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), this.getName());
maximoDataSet.open();

var sqlText = new String();
var printed = params["Printed"].toUpperCase().replace("Y","1");
var printed1 = printed.replace("N","0");
var where = new String(params["where"]);

if (params["Printed"].value)
    where += " and workorder.em_printed = '" + printed1 + "' "; 

// Add query to sqlText variable.
sqlText = "select workorder.wonum, workorder.workorderid as workorderid1, (select min(w2.workorderid) from maximo.workorder w2 where w2.istask=1 and w2.parent=workorder.wonum and w2.siteid=workorder.siteid) as workorderid, "
+ " workorder.pmnum as pmnum, workorder.targstartdate, workorder.siteid, workorder.description as wdesc, workorder.worktype, a.assetnum, a.description as adesc, a.em_relaymajor, a.em_relayminor, "
+ " workorder.location, l.description as ldesc, a.em_circuit, a.em_manfmodl, a.serialnum, j.em_craft, a.assetuid, "
+ " (select al.description from alndomain al where al.value=j.em_craft and al.domainid='EM_CRAFT') as cdesc, "
+ " (select wt.wtypedesc from maximo.worktype wt where wt.worktype=workorder.worktype) as wtdesc "
+ " from maximo.workorder "
+ " left outer join maximo.asset as a on a.assetnum=workorder.assetnum and a.siteid=workorder.siteid "
+ " left outer join maximo.jobplan as j on j.jpnum=workorder.jpnum and j.pluscrevnum=workorder.pluscjprevnum "
+ " left outer join maximo.locations as l on l.location=workorder.location and l.siteid=workorder.siteid"
// Include the Maximo where clause
+ " where workorder.istask=0 and workorder.status='INPRG' and workorder.siteid='EM' and " + where
;

maximoDataSet.setQuery(sqlText);
```

Fetch Script:

```
if (!maximoDataSet.fetch())
    return (false);

// Add a line for each output column
// The specific get method should match the data type of the output column.
row["wonum"] = maximoDataSet.getString("wonum");
row["workorderid"] = maximoDataSet.getString("workorderid");
row["workorderid1"] = maximoDataSet.getString("workorderid1");
row["wdesc"] = maximoDataSet.getString("wdesc");
row["worktype"] = maximoDataSet.getString("worktype");
row["assetnum"] = maximoDataSet.getString("assetnum");
row["location"] = maximoDataSet.getString("location");
row["adesc"] = maximoDataSet.getString("adesc");    
row["ldesc"] = maximoDataSet.getString("ldesc");
row["em_circuit"] = maximoDataSet.getString("em_circuit");
row["em_manfmodl"] = maximoDataSet.getString("em_manfmodl");
row["serialnum"] = maximoDataSet.getString("serialnum");
row["em_craft"] = maximoDataSet.getString("em_craft");  
row["cdesc"] = maximoDataSet.getString("cdesc");
row["wtdesc"] = maximoDataSet.getString("wtdesc");
row["pmnum"] = maximoDataSet.getString("pmnum");
row["siteid"] = maximoDataSet.getString("siteid");
row["assetuid"] = maximoDataSet.getString("assetuid");
row["em_relaymajor"] = maximoDataSet.getString("em_relaymajor");
row["em_relayminor"] = maximoDataSet.getString("em_relayminor");
row["targstartdate"] = maximoDataSet.getTimestamp("targstartdate");

// Long Description
    longDescDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), "longDescDataSet");
    longDescDataSet.open();



    longDescSQL = "select longdescription.ldtext  "
    + "from longdescription "
    + "where longdescription.ldownertable='WORKORDER' and longdescription.ldownercol='DESCRIPTION' "
    + "and longdescription.ldownercol='DESCRIPTION' "
    + "and longdescription.ldkey=?";

    longDescDataSet.setQuery(longDescSQL);

    longDescDataSet.setQueryParameterValue(1, maximoDataSet.getString("workorderid"));

    if(longDescDataSet.fetch()) {
        row["longdesc"] = longDescDataSet.getString("ldtext");
    }
    longDescDataSet.close();
// End Long Description

// Last Major
    lastmajorDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), "lastmajorDataSet");
    lastmajorDataSet.open();

    lastmajorSQL = "select workorder.wonum as wn1, workorder.workorderid as wid1, workorder.description as d1, p.frequency as f1, p.frequnit as fu1, "
    + "p.lastcompdate as lc1, p.extdate as e1, p.nextdate as n1, workorder.targstartdate as tsd1 "
    + "from workorder "
    + "join pm as p on p.pmnum=workorder.pmnum and p.siteid=workorder.siteid "
    + "where workorder.istask = 0 and workorder.actfinish = (select max(w1.actfinish) from maximo.workorder as w1 where w1.wonum=workorder.wonum and w1.siteid=workorder.siteid) "
    + "and workorder.worktype = 'MAJPM' and workorder.assetnum=? and workorder.siteid=? ";


    lastmajorDataSet.setQuery(lastmajorSQL);

    lastmajorDataSet.setQueryParameterValue(1, maximoDataSet.getString("assetnum"));
    lastmajorDataSet.setQueryParameterValue(2, maximoDataSet.getString("siteid"));

    if(lastmajorDataSet.fetch()) {
        row["wn1"] = lastmajorDataSet.getString("wn1");
        row["wid1"] = lastmajorDataSet.getString("wid1");
        row["d1"] = lastmajorDataSet.getString("d1");
        row["f1"] = lastmajorDataSet.getString("f1");
        row["lc1"] = lastmajorDataSet.getTimestamp("lc1");
        row["fu1"] = lastmajorDataSet.getString("fu1");
        row["e1"] = lastmajorDataSet.getTimestamp("e1");
        row["n1"] = lastmajorDataSet.getTimestamp("n1");
        row["tsd1"] = lastmajorDataSet.getTimestamp("tsd1");
    }
    lastmajorDataSet.close();
// End Last Major

// Last Major Initials
    lastmajorIDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), "lastmajorIDataSet");
    lastmajorIDataSet.open();

    lastmajorISQL =" WITH x(key, val, rnum) AS "
    + " (SELECT refwo, em_initials, row_number() over(partition by refwo) "
    + " from maximo.labtrans as labtrans "
    + " join maximo.person as person on person.personid=labtrans.laborcode where labtrans.refwo='" + row["wn1"] + "' and labtrans.siteid=?), "
    + " y(key, str, cnt, cnt_max) AS "
    + " ( SELECT key, VARCHAR('', 1000), 0, MAX(rnum) "
    + " FROM x "
    + " GROUP BY key "
    + " UNION ALL "
    + " SELECT y.key, y.str || RTRIM(CHAR(x.val)) || ',', y.cnt + 1, y.cnt_max "
    + " FROM x, y "
    + " WHERE x.key = y.key AND "
    + " x.rnum = y.cnt + 1 AND "
    + " y.cnt < y.cnt_max ) "
    + " SELECT key, str "
    + " FROM y "
    + " WHERE y.cnt = y.cnt_max ";

    lastmajorIDataSet.setQuery(lastmajorISQL);

    //lastmajorIDataSet.setQueryParameterValue(1, lastmajorDataSet.getString("wn1"));
    lastmajorIDataSet.setQueryParameterValue(1, maximoDataSet.getString("siteid"));

    if(lastmajorIDataSet.fetch()) {
        row["str"] = lastmajorIDataSet.getString("str");
    }
    lastmajorIDataSet.close();
// End Last Major Initials

// Last Major Long Description
    LMlongDescDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), "LMlongDescDataSet");
    LMlongDescDataSet.open();

    LMlongDescSQL = "select longdescription.ldtext as ldtext1  "
    + "from longdescription "
    + "where longdescription.ldownertable='WORKORDER' and longdescription.ldownercol='DESCRIPTION' "
    + "and longdescription.ldkey=" + row["wid1"];


    LMlongDescDataSet.setQuery(LMlongDescSQL);

    //LMlongDescDataSet.setQueryParameterValue(1, lastmajorDataSet.getString("wid1"));

    if(LMlongDescDataSet.fetch()) {
        row["longdesc1"] = LMlongDescDataSet.getString("ldtext1");
    }
    LMlongDescDataSet.close();
// End Last Major Long Description

// Last Minor
    lastminorDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), "lastminorDataSet");
    lastminorDataSet.open();

    lastminorSQL = "select workorder.wonum as wn2, workorder.workorderid as wid2, workorder.description as d2, p.frequency as f2, p.frequnit as fu2, "
    + "p.lastcompdate as lc2, p.extdate as e2, p.nextdate as n2, workorder.targstartdate as tsd2 "
    + "from workorder "
    + "join pm as p on p.pmnum=workorder.pmnum and p.siteid=workorder.siteid "
    + "where workorder.istask = 0 and workorder.actfinish = (select max(w1.actfinish) from maximo.workorder as w1 where w1.wonum=workorder.wonum and w1.siteid=workorder.siteid) "
    + "and workorder.worktype = 'MINPM' and workorder.assetnum=? and workorder.siteid= ? ";

    lastminorDataSet.setQuery(lastminorSQL);

    lastminorDataSet.setQueryParameterValue(1, maximoDataSet.getString("assetnum"));
    lastminorDataSet.setQueryParameterValue(2, maximoDataSet.getString("siteid"));

    if(lastminorDataSet.fetch()) {
        row["wn2"] = lastminorDataSet.getString("wn2");
        row["wid2"] = lastminorDataSet.getString("wid2");
        row["d2"] = lastminorDataSet.getString("d2");
        row["f2"] = lastminorDataSet.getString("f2");
        row["lc2"] = lastminorDataSet.getTimestamp("lc2");
        row["fu2"] = lastminorDataSet.getString("fu2");
        row["e2"] = lastminorDataSet.getTimestamp("e2");
        row["n2"] = lastminorDataSet.getTimestamp("n2");
        row["tsd2"] = lastminorDataSet.getTimestamp("tsd2");
    }
    lastminorDataSet.close();
// End Last Minor

// Last Minor Initials
    lastminorIDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), "lastminorIDataSet");
    lastminorIDataSet.open();

    lastminorISQL =" WITH x(key, val, rnum) AS "
    + " (SELECT refwo, em_initials, row_number() over(partition by refwo) "
    + " from maximo.labtrans as labtrans "
    + " join maximo.person as person on person.personid=labtrans.laborcode where labtrans.refwo='" + row["wn2"] + "' and labtrans.siteid=?), "
    + " y(key, str1, cnt, cnt_max) AS "
    + " ( SELECT key, VARCHAR('', 1000), 0, MAX(rnum) "
    + " FROM x "
    + " GROUP BY key "
    + " UNION ALL "
    + " SELECT y.key, y.str1 || RTRIM(CHAR(x.val)) || ',', y.cnt + 1, y.cnt_max "
    + " FROM x, y "
    + " WHERE x.key = y.key AND "
    + " x.rnum = y.cnt + 1 AND "
    + " y.cnt < y.cnt_max ) "
    + " SELECT key, str1 "
    + " FROM y "
    + " WHERE y.cnt = y.cnt_max ";

    lastminorIDataSet.setQuery(lastminorISQL);

    //lastminorIDataSet.setQueryParameterValue(1, lastminorDataSet.getString("wn2"));
    lastminorIDataSet.setQueryParameterValue(1, maximoDataSet.getString("siteid"));

    if(lastminorIDataSet.fetch()) {
        row["str1"] = lastminorIDataSet.getString("str1");
    }
    lastminorIDataSet.close();
// End Last Minor Initials

// Last Minor Long Description
    LM2longDescDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), "LM2longDescDataSet");
    LM2longDescDataSet.open();

    LM2longDescSQL = "select longdescription.ldtext as ldtext2  "
    + "from longdescription "
    + "where longdescription.ldownertable='WORKORDER' and longdescription.ldownercol='DESCRIPTION' "
    + "and longdescription.ldkey=" + row["wid2"];

    LM2longDescDataSet.setQuery(LM2longDescSQL);

    //LM2longDescDataSet.setQueryParameterValue(1, lastminorDataSet.getString("wid2"));

    if(LM2longDescDataSet.fetch()) {
        row["longdesc2"] = LM2longDescDataSet.getString("ldtext2");
    }
    LM2longDescDataSet.close();
// End Last Minor Long Description

// Asset Long Description
    AlongDescDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), "AlongDescDataSet");
    AlongDescDataSet.open();

    AlongDescSQL = "select longdescription.ldtext as ldtext3  "
    + "from longdescription "
    + "where longdescription.ldownertable='ASSET' and longdescription.ldownercol='DESCRIPTION' "
    + "and longdescription.ldkey=?";

    AlongDescDataSet.setQuery(AlongDescSQL);

    AlongDescDataSet.setQueryParameterValue(1, maximoDataSet.getString("assetuid"));

    if(AlongDescDataSet.fetch()) {
        row["longdesc3"] = AlongDescDataSet.getString("ldtext3");
    }
    AlongDescDataSet.close();
// End Asset Long Description

myTxn = MXReportTxnProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName());
myStmt = myTxn.createStatement();
myStmt.setQuery("update workorder set workorder.em_printed = '1' where workorder.em_printed = '0' and workorder.workorderid = ? ");
myStmt.setQueryParameterValue(1,row["workorderid1"]); 
//myStmt.setQueryParameterValue(2,"'"+row["siteid"]+"'");
myTxn.save();

return (true);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMK9h.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding the debug statements to see which querries are actualy ran? Then see how many records you get back. Add those together and it should be lower then your max record limit set in preferences